# Custom sharedpreferences in BaseAdapter Context null

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, baseadapter

I have custom SharedPreference class and i try to get a string from my custom SharedPrefecenses class. I got error in getView method when " prf = new PrefManager(context);"

What can i do, i have been searching 2 days.

```
public class PrefManager {
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context _context;

int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

private static final String PREF_NAME = "Secur-transact";

private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";

public PrefManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public String getString(String PREF_NAME) {
    if(pref.contains(PREF_NAME)){
        return pref.getString(PREF_NAME,null);
    }
    return  "";
}
```

}

I try to get getString method in adapter view.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

PrefManager prf;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    prf = new PrefManager(context); // I GOT ERROR IN HERE

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);


    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    if (prf.getString("ColorName").equals("RED")) {
        name.setBackgroundResource(R.color.primaryLightColorRed);
        name.setTextColor(R.color.colorWhite);
    }
```

> initializing here

```
public class SampleClass extends Fragment {

private List<ModelsProps> modelsPropsList = new ArrayList<ModelsProps>();
public SampleClass () {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    final CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), modelsPropsList);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You're using `ListView` instead of `RecyclerView`. How old is the tutorial you're following? Always look for something recent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are probably not initializing the variable `context`.

Just try to change the line:

```
prf = new PrefManager(context);
```

to:

```
prf = new PrefManager(parent.getContext());
```

Comment: Its still same. in logcat android.content.Context android.view.View.getContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: @user2293754 post the code from where you are initializing the class `CustomListAdapter`

Comment: thank you very much. Your answer give me an idea. I changed code to " prf = new PrefManager(parent.getContext()); " it works right now. Can you edit your answer ? I will accept it to correct.

Comment: @Yasin Yes convertView will be null initially

Comment: `getView` is called every time an item is supposed to be put on screen. You don't need to create and destroy a new `PrefManager` every single time that happens. Pass a single instance to your adapter constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass context from fragment to your adapter in constructer and then pass it from adapter to preference Class.

Comment: Hi, please help explain your ideas by including a code sample.